# Dear departed or dearly departed

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

A **"Dear departed"** is a dead person, as referred to at a funeral. [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-dear-departed) explains it this way: *British English* literary a person you love who has died.

However, I often see "dearly departed" in articles, books, films and even songs.

Does **"dearly"** convey several dead people?
Is it an adverb here that means **"at a great cost"**?

What in the world does "Dearly departed" mean?

Here's the [NGram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dearly+departed%2Cdear+departed&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdearly%20departed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdear%20departed%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: The formulaic expression **dearly departed** seems to have emerged in the mid 19th century, and **dear departed** in the early 18th century (per a lazy ngram search). I suspect some obituary column editor felt an adverb was needed to modify **departed** and that (bogus) edit "stuck". Possibly influenced by **dearly beloved**.

Comment: It's been discussed on Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.usage.english/oqKCdSpCrnM. There is no clear answer there, as far as I understood it's an illogical but accepted and used phrase. The posters talk of dearly beloved etymology-by-analogy, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is *dear* to you if it matters very much to you.  It's used in formal speech as a sign of politeness.

*Dearly X* is the adverb form of *dear* meaning "X in a dear manner" - meaning the way X is done matters very much to us.  So *dearly departed* technically means "departed in a way that was dear to someone" - which essentially evaluates to that we hope someone passes away in a way that they are now peaceful.

*Dear departed* is using *dear* as an adjective  and it simply means the person who is departed is dear to us.

They differ in technical meaning but can be used in the same situations.

Answer (score 1):

It's a minor malapropism attributable to conflation of the adjective "dear" with the the adverb "dearly", which related term begins the customary salutation "dearly beloved" of congregants by a celebrant, as in e.g. "Dearly Beloved, we are gathered here today to mourn the passing of (and to celebrate the worthy life of) our dear friend . . ."; also "whom we dearly miss"

The mis-usage is humorously exemplified in Richard Pryor's "Eulogy" bit, which begins:

> We are... gathered here today on this soft occasion, to say goodbye to the dearly departed; he was dearly, and he has departed. Thus, that's why we call him the dearly departed.

(the rest of the bit continues rather ribaldly)